# Azure Cloud Services - Outbound connection rules - Only allow certain FQDN

Tags: azure

I have a cloud service on which I need very strict connectivity rules.

I therefore use NetworkSecurityGroup rules to block all inbound and outbound connections for my cloud service.

However, I need to allow a specific outbound connection. I cannot rely on IP ranges because it is an external API and the provider cannot guarantee a fixed IP for their service.

Is there a way to block all outbound connections except one site, based on a FQDN and not an IP range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Azure Security Groups are based solely on IP addresses.

The only way I can think that you could do this is to have some other process, that runs a script on a schedule to update the rules. Obviously this presumes you have a specific list of host names that you can resolve into IP addresses.

The only other method would be to purchase one of the premium firewall appliances that sit between your machine and the internet and do higher level filtering.